# Fix cursor position correct with contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I've tried to make a simple editor box and want to add the checkbox input onto it.

But when I add the checkbox, I found that the cursor didn't go right:

the caret is before the checkbox I added, and it can't go right even I hit my right arrow key. Any suggest to make it more correct? (I'm using a webbrowser based on webkit, just make it correct is fine. )

What I want to implement is **when I click the mouse or use keyboard to position the content, the caret should work as normal editor(word, evernote, etc).**

[image: Problem]

jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/cppgohan/84CTE/9/

### HTML:

```
<button id="add"> AddCheckbox </button>
<button id="add2"> AddCheckbox2 </button>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" width="500px" height="500">
    1. Make it work <input type="checkbox"><br>
    2. Make it done <input type="checkbox" checked>
<div>
```

### JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $editor = $("#editor");
        $editor.append('<input type="checkbox">');
        $editor.focus();
    });
    ...
});
```

#### Hit backspace one by one, wired things happens:

[image: Hit backspace one by one, wired things happens]

Answer (score 1):

It is a long history bug of chromium.

**After more and more (re)search, it is a web browser Bug: [chromium bug: Caret moves incorrectly around check boxes and radio buttons in contentEditable div](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2875)**

#### What is the expected result?

Using the arrow keys to place the caret immediately after a check box or 
radio button should result in the caret being rendered in that spot.

#### What happens instead?

The caret is rendered to the left of and slightly down from the radio 
button or check box.

Seems chrome has postponed the issuefix

## The solution I finally got:

I use a `<img>` tag instead of real `<input>` tag, use `checkbox_check` `checkbox_uncheck` class to toggle the image check or uncheck.

It works fine, I also tried to write the function for setting/getting content from the editor view, and use `regex::replace` for transforming between `<input>` and `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

I have Added some javascript code and now it's work as expected:

```
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
    {
        var range,selection;
        if(document.createRange)
        {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
            range.collapse(false);
            selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
        else if(document.selection)
        { 
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
            range.collapse(false);
            range.select();
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natchkebiailia/84CTE/10/)

Comment: Saddly that did not help so much though.

Comment: @Gohan it does what you wanted though. What the problem then?

Comment: I know how to move the caret, What I want to implement is when I click the mouse or use keyboard to position the content, the caret should work as normal editor(word, evernote, etc).

Comment: @Gohan I did not get it. You wanted to move caret at the end after inserting the checkbox and that's working well. What is unusual in caret? It works as it should! If you don't add  empty symbol after input tag, there is no way to move caret after checkbox!

Comment: maybe you are not using chrome, seems the problem is webkit only

Comment: http://zippy.gfycat.com/PresentShowyAmurstarfish.gif  here id a demo on chrome. please state a problem! @Gohan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51146/discussion-between-gohan-and-mr-ilia)